# In the official helm chart, how do you specify the subpath for the dags when using persistence volume claim?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

It was working before with the previous chart which I think was the community version. Since the official helm has been created/launched, I want to migrate to the official one. I did not see that you can specify a subPath. This is for Airflow 2.2.3

It will get this error in helm upgrade/install:
`dags.persistence: Additional property subPath is not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

In the official Helm Chart You wont have a subpath folder. By enabling the persistence you refer to the PVC which is mounted in the airflow container . Lets say at `/opt/airflow/dags/my/dag_directory/` Now if you want the DAGS to be loaded from just the folder dag_directory. You should change the `AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER={AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/my/dag_directory`. As far as `subPath` parameter is concerned, it is a part of `gitSync` under dags, which refers to the directory within the repo which we want to clone.